# How to customize the shape of a column chart in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

Can anybody tell me how to customize the shape of a column chart in extjs? By default the column chart with the top edge or corner appears flat. I want to display it with rounded corners for top edges.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without rewriting some parts of the Bar chart code. You can define a renderer for the series as follows:

```
series: [{
    renderer: function(sprite, record, barAttr, index, store){
        barAttr.radius=5;
        return barAttr;
    },
...
```

But this will make all the corners rounded. The sprite type for Bar charts is hard coded as 'rect' in Bar.js drawSeries, and this can't be semi rounded. You may want to rewrite it with 'path' sprite.
Would love to know of a better solution..

Comment: Thanks for reply as you said your code make rounded for all corner.can you tell how to rewrite it with path sprite

Comment: Not really, sorry, have a look at [Bar.js](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Bar.html#Ext-chart-series-Bar), Seems like quite a lot of work to me